# Append IENumerator output to variable

Tags: unity-game-engine, ienumerator

I'm trying to make simple get requests on Unity and append the result to the variable I want so I can use it later. How can I achieve this in my example code?

```c#
void Start()
{
    // The following code is not working due to convertion between string and Coroutine.
    string response1 = StartCoroutine(GetRequest("http://httpbin.org/get"));
    string response2 = StartCoroutine(GetRequest("http://httpbin.org/get", new string[] { "name=john", "surname=doe" }));
    // debug response1 and response2 when the proccess completes.
}

IEnumerator GetRequest(string url, string[] parameters = null)
{
    string parameter = "";

    if(parameters != null)
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++)
        {
            parameter += ((i==0) ? "?" : "&") + parameters[i];
        }
    }

    UnityWebRequest req = UnityWebRequest.Get(url + parameter);
    yield return req.SendWebRequest();

    if (req.isNetworkError || req.isHttpError)
    {
        Debug.Log(req.error);
        yield return req.error;
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log(req.downloadHandler.text);
        yield return req.downloadHandler.text;    
    }
}
```

Comment: The `StartCoroutine` function returns [`Coroutine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Coroutine.html) not `string`.

Comment: @Programmer Yes. I already put that in the code. I'm asking how to return a string from a coroutine...

Comment: No you did nt. You are assigning Coroutine to a string variable. See the duplicate for how to return something from the coroutine and call it in order. The code in the duplicate should return the request status but you can easily change it to return the data.